# Weaker definitions of clusters in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, definition, clustering

A cluster in a graph is most naturally defined as a maximal complete subgraph. But this is too strict a definition to be of practical use: in most (especially random) graphs there will be only rather small clusters according to this definition.

One way to weaken the definition is to allow a not too large subset of edges in the complete subgraph to be missing. Two questions arise:

How large may the set of missing edges be choosen?

How would one guarantee that the missing edges are equally distributed over the graph (so that it stays connected)?

**Question 1**: Where can I learn more about this approach? References from the graph clustering literature?

Another possible weakening of the definition starts from the observation that in a complete graph the maximal distance between two of its nodes is 1. This leads naturally to the definition of a $k$-cluster being a maximal subgraph such that the maximal distance between two of its nodes is $k$. For $k=2$ this would imply that half of the edges of the complete subgraph may be missing, and it's still a cluster.

**Question 2**: Has this approach been taken before in the graph clustering literature?

Comment: Note that much more than half of the edges may be missing in a $2$-cluster; for instance the star graph $K_{1,\ell}$ is a $2$-cluster. In terms of social network graphs, this means that every individual celebrity generates a $2$-cluster (whereas $1$-clusters are typically formed by groups of mutual friends/colleagues/etc.). I'm not sure this is what you want, but in any case it doesn't answer your question. Alas, I am oblivious to any existing graph clustering literature. (I would suggest looking at subgraphs with high [connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/k-connected_graph) instead.)